# Would love some clarification on group by combined with max (or min)

Tags: mysql, group-by, max

I have a table of data points for users and am trying to pivot it using a group by, a min, and a case.

So..

user_data:

```
user_id | data_type_id | value
1       |    1         |    'Joe'
1       |    2         |    'Blow'
2       |    1         |    'Mary'
2       |    2         |    'Jones'


select 
max( case when data_type_id = 1 then value end) as 'firstName',
max( case when data_type_id = 2 then value end) as 'lastName' 

from user_data group by user_id
```

This kind'a sort'a works, except that often the values are NULL even though there *are values for those data types in the dataset if I remove the group by and max.

I'm trying to understand what is happening behind the scenes here because it's very confusing. `group by` makes it look like there's only one row per user (I'm not sure how it decides which row... probably the first one?) but then somehow the case statement manages to find the info for rows that aren't displayed.

I'd really appreciate some help in understanding what's happening here so that I can get the data I'm actually seeking.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is to transpose the rows (*data_type_id*) into column. When you execute the following statement,

```
SELECT user_id,
       CASE WHEN data_type_id = 1 THEN value END  firstName,
       CASE WHEN data_type_id = 2 THEN value END  lastName 
FROM   TableName
```

it will give you the following result,

```
╔═════════╦═══════════╦══════════╗
║ USER_ID ║ FIRSTNAME ║ LASTNAME ║
╠═════════╬═══════════╬══════════╣
║       1 ║ Joe       ║ (null)   ║
║       1 ║ (null)    ║ Blow     ║
║       2 ║ Mary      ║ (null)   ║
║       2 ║ (null)    ║ Jones    ║
╚═════════╩═══════════╩══════════╝
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/82a38/3)

Notice that the value are `(null)` when it does not met the condition in your `CASE` statement.

In order to categorized `user_id` into a row for every group and eliminate those `null` values, the aggregate function `MAX()` is applied on rows: `firstname` and `lastname`.

```
SELECT user_id,
       MAX(CASE WHEN data_type_id = 1 THEN value END)  firstName,
       MAX(CASE WHEN data_type_id = 2 THEN value END)  lastName 
FROM   TableName 
GROUP  BY user_id
```

thus giving you the following result,

```
╔═════════╦═══════════╦══════════╗
║ USER_ID ║ FIRSTNAME ║ LASTNAME ║
╠═════════╬═══════════╬══════════╣
║       1 ║ Joe       ║ Blow     ║
║       2 ║ Mary      ║ Jones    ║
╚═════════╩═══════════╩══════════╝
```

Comment: Right... but what I'm not clear on is if I do a `group by user_id` without the `max` then there is just one row per user.  So... HOW is `max` finding these other rows in a result that seemingly doesn't contain them?

Comment: oh i get it. This only works in mysql though. What it does is it randomly selects values on non-aggregated column (*firstname and lastname*). You cannot clearly see here as you have only few rows in the table.

Comment: *The server is free to choose any value from each group, so unless they are the same, the values chosen are indeterminate.* from [MySQL Docs : MySQL Extensions to GROUP BY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-extensions.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
max( case when data_type_id = 1 then value else '' end) as 'firstName',
max( case when data_type_id = 2 then value else '' end) as 'lastName' 

from user_data group by user_id
```

will probably get what you want

Comment: yes, it seems to much of the time (though not 100%) which is what I'm trying to understand.

Comment: what are you trying to understand?

Comment: how `group by` and max and case work together.  As I said, the `group by` will produce one row per user, however, the case digs up values for rows that aren't displayed.  So... I'm trying to understand what's actually happening, so I can visualize the query, and react accordingly.

Comment: @Ashalynd, Sorry... to be clearer, I'm not trying to get rid of the NULL, I understand how to do that. The point is the value isn't *actually NULL... there IS a first name for a given user, but it comes up as NULL sometimes.  I'm not clear on why.

Comment: GROUP BY goes over all rows, and CASE modifies them as you go. Then you apply your aggregate function to every row. The results are what you get.